# How to use BySelector depth method with min, max params?

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I would like to use this function:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/BySelector#depth(int,int)
but `BySelector` has package private constructor, so I'm unable to instantiate it. Instead the doc says:

> Clients should not instanciate this class directly. Use the By factory
> class instead.

but `By` class has only this method with one parameter:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/By#depth(int)

Am I doomed to using some ugly loop checking all depths or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `By` factory:

```
import androidx.test.uiautomator.By

device.findObjects(By.text("some text"))
```